# Can model views in Flask-Admin hyperlink to other model views?

Tags: python, flask

Let's suppose we have a model, `Foo`, that references another model, `User` - and there are Flask-Admin's `ModelView` for both.

On the `Foo` admin view page

[image]

I would like the entries in the `User` column to be linked to the corresponding `User` model view.

Do I need to modify one of Flask-Admin's templates to achieve this?

(This is possible in the Django admin interface by simply outputting HTML for a given field and setting `allow_tags` [(ref)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) True to bypass Django's HTML tag filter)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `column_formatters` for this: https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask.ext.admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters

Idea is pretty simple: for a field that you want to display as hyperlink, either generate a HTML string and wrap it with Jinja2 `Markup` class (so it won't be escaped in templates) or use `macro` helper: https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/template.py

Macro helper allows you to use custom Jinja2 macros in overridden template, which moves presentational logic to templates.

As far as URL is concerned, all you need is to find endpoint name generated (or provided) for the `User` model and do `url_for('userview.edit_view', id=model.id)` to generate the link.

Comment: Works great - thanks. The missing link for me was using jinja2.Markup.

Answer (score 40):

Some example code based on Joes' answer:

```
class MyFooView(ModelView):

    def _user_formatter(view, context, model, name):
        return Markup(
            u"<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (
                url_for('user.edit_view', id=model.user.id),
                model.user
            )
        ) if model.user else u""

    column_formatters = {
        'user': _user_formatter
    }
```

Comment: Great example! In my case I didn't need the url_for because they were external links, but great regardless.

Answer (score 0):

extra information for @wodow, notice that `model.user` is wrong if you use pymongo as the backend, because the model in pymongo is a dict type, you can just use `model['name']` to replace it

Answer (score -1):

Adding this code to each of your models that have referenced by other models and flask-admin and jinja will take care of the name you want to display on the screen, just replace that with whatever you prefer:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name  # or self.id or whatever you prefer
```

for example:

```
class Role(db.Document, RoleMixin):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    description = db.StringField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class MasterUser(db.Document, UserMixin):
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
    roles = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Role), default=[])
```